# Left alignment of "title" in KOMA letter

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

Hello to all members of this great TeX community. I have a question regarding the alignment of the title (subject) of KOMMA type letter. This is the letter code

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \setkomavar{frombank}{(1234)\,567\,890}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{fixltx2e}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{grffile}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{wrapfig}
 \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{textcomp}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{capt-of}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{xunicode}
 \usepackage{minted}
 \setkomavar{fromname}{Enrico Pirani}
 \setkomavar{fromemail}{enrico.pirani@gmail.com }
 \KOMAoption{fromemail}{false}
 \setkomavar{fromphone}{3926224668}
 \KOMAoption{fromphone}{true}
 \KOMAoption{backaddress}{false}
 \setkomavar{place}{}
 \KOMAoptions{foldmarks=true}
 \LoadLetterOption{NF}
 \setkomavar{signature}{Jane}
 \setkomavar{fromaddress}{Some Street 1\\\\
  12345 Some City}
 \date{18 Settembre, 2016}
 \hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={Enrico Pirani},
  pdftitle={ A simple letter},
  pdfkeywords={},
  pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 24.5.1 (Org mode 8.3.1)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

\setkomavar{title}{A simple letter}

\begin{letter}{%
 John Doe\\\\
 Other Street 1\\\\
 54321 Other City}

\opening{}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enimad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\closing{}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

And this is the result

[image: Letter]

What I need is to move the title *A simple letter* to the left.

Comment: Try `\renewcommand*{\raggedsubject}{\raggedright}`.

Comment: @Johannes_B tried but with no result (output is the same)

Comment: You confused me by equalising title and subject. Try `\addtokomafont{title}{\raggedright}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can smuggle in the command to have text flushed to the left via `\addtokomafont`.

[image: enricopiraniScrlttrAlignSubject]

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Enrico Pirani}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{3926224668}
\KOMAoption{fromphone}{true}
\KOMAoption{backaddress}{false}
\setkomavar{place}{}
\KOMAoptions{foldmarks=true}
\setkomavar{signature}{Jane}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Some Street 1\\
12345 Some City}
\addtokomafont{title}{\raggedright}
\begin{document}

\setkomavar{subject}{Why are they so cute?}
\setkomavar{title}{Wombats}

\begin{letter}{%
    John Doe\\
    Other Street 1\\
    54321 Other City}

    \opening{Dear John,}

    Can you find out, why Wombats are so cute? \blindtext 

    \closing{Best regards}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```